# Regex to match hashtag character with string format in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a Regex to match a certain string format in javascript,

A hashtag symbol `'#'` has to be first and last character , There must be strings between these two characters,

If the string is more than one there must be two hashtag `'##'` symbol between each of them there is no limit to strings number.

Ex.

1. #string1##string2##string3##...##string4#
2. #string1#
3. #string##string2#

Comment: What is your expectation on this? You want to print true/false values or all matched strings?

Comment: in your examples you havent provided the expected output.....

Comment: i need to print true if matches following format @NickVu

Comment: I need to print true if it matches with the formats in questiong @mrtechtroid

Comment: What's the definition for a "string" that's between the '#'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the below regex with this pattern

`#[^\#]+#`: All characters (except `#`) between `##`

`(#[^\#]+#)+`: At least a string matched the pattern

`^` and `$`: Start and end of regex

```js
const checkRegex = (value) => {
  const regex = /^(#[^\#]+#)+$/
  return regex.test(value)
}

console.log(checkRegex("#test")) //false
console.log(checkRegex("#test#")) //true
console.log(checkRegex("#test##")) //false
console.log(checkRegex("#test##test#")) //true
console.log(checkRegex("#test##test##")) //false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```